# ¿Cómo mostrar los valores descriptivos de una determinada manera para un modelo logit binomial y qué otro paquete usar para mostrar los datos?

Tags: r, tablas, r-markdown, visualización-de-datos

Estoy intentando elaborar una **tabla estilizada** en **Rmarkdown** de análisis descriptivo para mi **modelo logit binomial**.

Por ahora, utilizo el comando `descr`  de la librería `summarytools` y la librería `printr` de la siguiente manera (con mi propio data.frame):

````
```{r , eval=TRUE, echo=FALSE}
library(printr)
df<-mtcars
library(summarytools)
descr(datos_modelo, stats = c("mean", "sd", "max", "min"), na.rm =TRUE)
````

El problema es que la tabla que se me genera pone los valores descriptivos en las columnas y las variables por filas. Pero tengo muchas variables. así que sería más correcto que los descriptivos estuvieran en las filas y las variables en las columnas.

**¿Cómo puedo "trasponer" esta tabla?**

Sabiendo que estoy elaborando un **logit binomial** con el paquete `glm` con **variables categóricas** (tipo factor para que R me entienda) tanto para la variable endógena como para la **mayoría de las variables exógenas**, ¿Hay algún paquete recomendado específicamente para este tipo de análisis descriptivo? Veo que tengo a mi disposición muchos paquetes pero no sé cuál es el que mas adecuado para mi trabajo.

Comment: ¿Has probado el transpose clasico: `t()`? Algo así: `t(descr(mtcars, stats = c("mean", "sd", "max", "min"), na.rm =TRUE))`

Comment: No lo había probado (ni me lo planteé al no ser una matriz tradicional) y funciona ¿Cómo podría alterar el orden en que aparecen las variables? Ahora mismo sigue un orden alfabético y quiero que sigan el orden que tienen en el dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imaginando que tienes algo así:

```
descr(mtcars, stats = c("mean", "sd", "max", "min"))

Descriptive Statistics  
mtcars  
N: 32  

                  am   carb    cyl     disp   drat   gear       hp     mpg    qsec     vs     wt
------------- ------ ------ ------ -------- ------ ------ -------- ------- ------- ------ ------
         Mean   0.41   2.81   6.19   230.72   3.60   3.69   146.69   20.09   17.85   0.44   3.22
      Std.Dev   0.50   1.62   1.79   123.94   0.53   0.74    68.56    6.03    1.79   0.50   0.98
          Max   1.00   8.00   8.00   472.00   4.93   5.00   335.00   33.90   22.90   1.00   5.42
          Min   0.00   1.00   4.00    71.10   2.76   3.00    52.00   10.40   14.50   0.00   1.51
```

Puedes usar el tradicional "transpose" de matrices, `t()` esto por que la salida de `descr()` es un objeto que hereda de la clase `matrix`:

```
t(descr(mtcars, stats = c("mean", "sd", "max", "min")))
Descriptive Statistics  
mtcars  
N: 32  

               Mean   Std.Dev      Max     Min
---------- -------- --------- -------- -------
        am     0.41      0.50     1.00    0.00
      carb     2.81      1.62     8.00    1.00
       cyl     6.19      1.79     8.00    4.00
      disp   230.72    123.94   472.00   71.10
      drat     3.60      0.53     4.93    2.76
      gear     3.69      0.74     5.00    3.00
        hp   146.69     68.56   335.00   52.00
       mpg    20.09      6.03    33.90   10.40
      qsec    17.85      1.79    22.90   14.50
        vs     0.44      0.50     1.00    0.00
        wt     3.22      0.98     5.42    1.51

class(descr(mtcars, stats = c("mean", "sd", "max", "min")))
[1] "summarytools" "matrix"
```

Y finalmente para mantener el orden orginal de las columnas, puedes hacer esto:

```
new.df <- t(descr(mtcars, stats = c("mean", "sd", "max", "min"), na.rm =TRUE))
new.df[order(match(rownames(new.df), colnames(mtcars))),]

          Mean     Std.Dev     Max    Min
mpg   20.090625   6.0269481  33.900 10.400
cyl    6.187500   1.7859216   8.000  4.000
disp 230.721875 123.9386938 472.000 71.100
hp   146.687500  68.5628685 335.000 52.000
drat   3.596563   0.5346787   4.930  2.760
wt     3.217250   0.9784574   5.424  1.513
qsec  17.848750   1.7869432  22.900 14.500
vs     0.437500   0.5040161   1.000  0.000
am     0.406250   0.4989909   1.000  0.000
gear   3.687500   0.7378041   5.000  3.000
carb   2.812500   1.6152000   8.000  1.000
```

Con `order(match(rownames(new.df), colnames(mtcars)))` rehacemos el orden del  `data.frame` original, la única contra es que terminas obteniendo una matriz plana y no un objeto de tipo `summarytools`.

Comment: Cuando intento aplicar  `order(match(rownames(new.df), colnames(mtcars)))` para ordenar la matriz, R me devuelve solamente una lista/vector con los valores de la matriz y me aparece el siguiente mensaje: `## For best results, restart R session and update pander using devtools:: or remotes::install_github('rapporter/pander')`. Ya he ejecutado la segunda alternativa que ofrece dicho mensaje de error pero sigo obteniendo el vector, no me devuelve la matriz reordenada ¿Alguna idea de por qué ocurre esto?

Comment: Solucionado, simplemente era que no puse la coma que hay al final, justo antes del cierre de corchete.